# Recursion method java with String [] method

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a java code, but I can't solve it.

The exercise:

Make a recursive method in java called `String [] Yolo (int n)`. Only one argument allowed. The method should return all possible options in an array. So if you call the method `Yolo(2)` the method should print:

```
YoYo, 
YoLo, 
LoYo, 
LoLo.
```

And to make it more clear if the parameter is 3 it should be:

```
YoYoYo, 
YoYoLo, 
YoLoYo, 
YoLoLo
.....
```

This is my code so far:

```
public static String[] Yolo (int n){
    String yo = "yo";
    String lo = "lo";
    String[]  yolo = {};

    return Yolo(n); 
}
```

Comment: I recommend you review your class notes about recursion, and what its necessary parts are. Then think about how to express a solution for the problem in *n* in terms of the same problem in a smaller number (*n-1*, for example), which is the essence of recursion.

Comment: First try something and then ask if u face some problem. by the way how will your Yolo() method know the string inputs when you're not passing them.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava The strings are not input. They are given - "Yo" and "Lo".

Comment: correct. string yo and lo are not instance method or static variables. how will Yolo() method know for which string to output. String yo and lo are not in Yolo() method's scope.

Comment: Of course I tried already. It is not here in the code, but I thought about a solution, but I don't know how to solve this. That is the reason why I asked you.

Comment: If you can give me a hint on how to solve this problem it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The base case is : when n=1 , yolo returns yo , lo.
2. For other
       n values you call yolo method recursively and each time append yo
       and lo strings to every string in the result

.

```
public static String[] yolo(int n){
    String yo = "yo";
    String lo = "lo";
    if (n == 1){
        return new String[] {yo ,lo};
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (String s : yolo(n-1)){
        list.add(s + yo);
        list.add(s + lo);
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```